# Play 2.0 MySql keywords in models

Tags: mysql, playframework

Is it possible to use MySql's keywords for table/column (class/property) names in Play 2.0 models? I mean words like "match" (Match like like a football match)? I ask because by default the generated SQL does not enquote tabel/column names and so executing the generated SQL fails.

Comment: Have you tried? I'm almost possitive that it will work, but the easiest way to find out for sure, is just to try.

Comment: Yes I have, and like I said it fails because *match* is a keyword in MySQL and it's not enquoted

Answer (score 1):

The [JPA @Column annotation](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Column) let's you set the name of the field in the Database. Youc an use that so the generated SQL doesn't conflict with MySQL while keeping the Java name the same.

Comment: I know I can rename them, but this sux. Play should just enquote names (which would be easy for them to do) so it would work on any database.

Comment: @redman not all db may share the same restricted words, it's more work for the framework (and prone to bugs) when you have a valid and simple fix: rename with column annotation or choose another java name :)